# Manga about a guy trapped in a game and craft items to improve others, chased by three wizard sisters

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

Can someone help me find the title of the manga about a guy trapped in a video game?

He needs to complete all of the missions in the game but he realizes that he doesn't have any power and only can scan other game characters' abilities and increase their ability by crafting items.

In the first mission he needs to defeat a dragon, and a girl got killed (maybe his sister) that makes him want to revive her by using a rare item. He is able to make a team, about 4-5 people, with a girl that can heal, a girl with a wood sword, and a guy to help him search for the rare item. Then, he gets hunted by 3 wizard sisters because of his power to increase others' abilities. The 3 sisters are led by the older sister who has huge boobs. The 2nd sister has average boobs and the youngest has a flat chest. The 2nd or 3rd sister has the ability to control dolls and uses it to attack the main character while he is protecting a kingdom whete the king has been controlled by the 3 wizard sisters and has some plan for the kings daughter.

This manga came out around 2016-2018. Could be a game adaptation but I can't remember the game. I stopped reading it because the new chapter had a long release date and I forgot it. It had less than 20 chapters when I stopped reading it.